# ReKey Mysql / MariaDB Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables that all relate to a contact table using an email address as the primary relation key. I've added an autoincrement field to the contact table, but I'm looking for a convenient way to add that key to all the related tables. Is there one?

**Current Client Table**

| id | email | Field A | Field B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| new | email | data | data |

**Current Relation Table**

| email_key | Field A | Field B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email | data | data |

**Desired Relation Table**

| client_id | Field A | Field B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| # | data | data |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do something like below for each table.

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

UPDATE  desired_relation_table nwtbl
JOIN Contact c ON c.email = nwtbl.email_key
SET
nwtbl.client_id = c.id;

OR if you want insert to new table.

INSERT INTO new_relation_table
SELECT c.id,nwtbl.*  FROM Contact c JOIN desired_relation_table nwtbl ON c.email = nwtbl.email_key

Hope this helps!. Please let me know.

Comment: It appears this is exactly what I am looking for. I did not know you could use SET in that context. I'll give this a try here shortly and let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: please let me know if you have further challenges.